# How can I print texts line by line input using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

This is part of a sample `test.html` file:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
...
...
<table class="width-max">
            <tr>
             <td style="max-width: 300px; min-width:300px;">
              <a href="nowhere.com">
               <h2>
                <b>
                 <font size="3">
                  My College
                 </font>
                </b>
               </h2>
              </a>
              <h4>
               <font size="2">
                My Name
               </font>
               <br/>
              </h4>
              My Address
              <br/>
              My City, XY 19604
              <br/>
              My Country
              <br/>
              <br/>
              Email:
              <a href="javascript:NewWindow=window.open('nowhere.com;email=example@nowhere.edu','NewWindow','width=600,height=600,menubar=0');NewWindow.focus()">
               example@nowhere.edu
              </a>
              <br/>
              Website:
              <a href="http://www.nowhere.edu" target="newwindow">
               http://www.nowhere.edu
              </a>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
             </td>
              ...
              ...
</table>
<hr/>
<table class="width-max">
            <tr>
             <td style="max-width: 300px; min-width:300px;">
              <a href="nowhere.com">
               <h2>
                <b>
                 <font size="3">
                  His College
                 </font>
                </b>
               </h2>
              </a>
              <h4>
               <font size="2">
                His name
               </font>
               <br/>
              </h4>
              His Address
              <br/>
              His City, YX 49506
              <br/>
              His Country
              <br/>
              <br/>
              Phone: XX-YY-ZZ
              <br/>
              Email:
              <a href="javascript:NewWindow=window.open('nowhere.com;email=example@nowhere2.edu','NewWindow','width=600,height=600,menubar=0');NewWindow.focus()">
               example@nowhere2.edu
              </a>
              <br/>
              Website:
              <a href="http://nowhere2.edu/" target="newwindow">
               http://nowhere2.edu
              </a>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              ...
              ...
</table>
...
...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output I want:

```
My College
My Name
My Address
My City, XY 19604
My Country
Email:
example@nowhere.edu
Website:
http://www.nowhere.edu

His College
His Name
His Address
His City, YX 49506
His Country
Phone: XX-YY-ZZ
Email:
example@nowhere2.edu
Website:
http://www.nowhere2.edu
```

At first I tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('test.html', 'r') as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')

    tables = soup.find_all('table', class_='width-max')

    for table in tables:
        print(table.get_text())
```

It prints the texts in new lines but produces bunch of `blank lines` and `white spaces`:

```
         My College

      My Name
...
```

Then I tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('test.html', 'r') as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')
    tables = soup.find_all('table', class_='width-max')

    for table in tables:
        texts = ' '.join(table.text.split())
        print(texts)
```

It removes the `blank lines` and `white spaces` but combines all the texts in a single line:

```
My College My Name My Address ... ... http://www.nowhere2.edu
```

Finally I tried using `strip()` `stripped_strings()` method and I also tried to replace `<br>` with `\n` using `replace_with()` method. But I am not yet successful to print out the exact output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clean the `table.get_text()` values in order to print each line one after another.
With 2 regex you can do that by

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

with open('test.html', 'r') as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')
    tables = soup.find_all('table', class_='width-max')

    for table in tables:
        print(re.sub(r"(\n)+", r"\n", re.sub(r" {3,}", "", table.get_text().replace('...', ''))) , end="")
```

This will ouput

```
My College
My Name
My Address
My City, XY 19604
My Country
Email:
example@nowhere.edu
Website:
http://www.nowhere.edu    

His College
His name
His Address
His City, YX 49506
His Country
Phone: XX-YY-ZZ
Email:
example@nowhere2.edu
Website:
http://nowhere2.edu
```

The first regex  `{3,}` will remove all 3 or more empty lines and the second `"(\n)+", "\\n"` will substitute \n more than one with one \n that will make the print function to print the data line by line.
In addition, to match you expected output the `get_text().replace('...', '')` added to remove ... from the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try joining with a newline instead of space:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('test.html', 'r') as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')
    tables = soup.find_all('table', class_='width-max')
    for table in tables:
        texts = '\n'.join(table.text.split())
        print(texts)
```

Edit:
Previous snippet would break your multiple word lines into single word lines, try this instead:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
with open('test.html', 'r') as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')    
    tables = soup.find_all('table', class_='width-max')    
    for table in tables:
        if !table.get_text().isspace():
            text = os.linesep.join([l for l in table.get_text().splitlines() if l])
            print(text.lstrip())
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps. But it's printing each word in a single line.

Comment: it prints the texts in new lines but blank lines and white spaces are not avoided. I also used strip() method but still it prints unnecessary blank lines and white spaces. stripped_strings() does the job but it cannot be used for find_all().

Answer (score 0):

Just change your print statement and add newline there like this

```
print('\n' + texts)
```

Comment: Thanks. But it prints all the texts of a particular table in a single line. Then the texts of the next table and so on...